# Why setState re-renders even if state stays the same?

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
  }
  render() {
    alert('rendered');
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.index}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({index: 0})}>test</button>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

[image: Edit zw28l3ynkm]

I know we can define a `shouldComponentUpdate` to check if `this.state === nextState`, but why don't React check this by default? Same goes for props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React defaults to always re-rendering because then React by default is always correct regardless of what you have in your `state`.

Iterating the keys of `this.state` and using `===` works in your example, but with complex `state` it's not possible to use simple equality. Take the following example, the `indices` Array is the same Array so `===` would return `true`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    indices: [0],
  }
  render() {
    alert('rendered');
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.index}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => {
          this.state.indices.push(2);
          this.setState({indices: this.state.indices})
        }>test</button>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

State can have Arrays, Objects, etc., and React does not try to infer what "equality" means for them. If you want to optimize your components, you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` because you know what "equality" means for your own state.

If you are sure your component's state & props can be compared using simple equality, like in your example, you can extend [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) to get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Your example is not optimal because the React docs explicitly state that you should never mutate `this.state` directly.

Comment: @xehpuk Yes, good point. I simplified too much and chose a poor example. If you treat the full `state` treat as immutable, you would never have a problem. That's difficult to enforce and do correctly in JavaScript given how easy the language makes it to modify objects, which likely contributes to why React goes with re-rendering maybe too often: it means the DOM is guaranteed to be correct.